# How to set default database in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea

I'm using Database Tool Window of IDEA, and every I create a new project I have to set the data source in the new project.

Is there anyway to set a default data source in the Database Tool Window, so when I create a new project I can use it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the Data Source global so that it's available for all the projects automatically:

[image: make global]

Comment: my version is 2016.1.2, and the button does not exsit.

Comment: what is your version?

Comment: 2016.3.5, your version should have [the same button](http://i.imgur.com/qrB5VBi.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder could you please as well answer the "real" question? How to set the default dataSource for a project. Your answer is correct according to posts text, not to the post title.

Comment: @hgoebl there is no such setting.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed it by deleting the "wrong" datasource, then the desired (next?) datasource became the default.